# How can I keep position: absolute from covering up my content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have google map loading within a tab.  I am using position: absolute on the container div.

The map displays good. The problem I'm having is that the map covers up any content I try to put underneath it. I'd like to be able to put tables and text underneath the entire tabs all together, not just the map.

```
Here is the fiddle: Notice <p>I want to see this text.</p> is not showing up.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/67wu9/18/

Comment: I may be missing something, but I don't see anything hiding behind the map.

Comment: @JeremyMiller same here.

Comment: adding a paragraph works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/67wu9/17/

Comment: I updated the fiddle.  I am wanting to add it under the entire tab div. Not within the tab itself.  I want to continue content on my webpage underneath the tabs.

Answer (score 1):

I've forked your fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/3ag7G/

Is this what you're aiming for?

```
<!-- Wrapper-->
<div style="position: absolute;">
```

Make the wrapper div absolute and place everything that you want inside of it.  If not then then easiest thing I can think of is to position your box with xy coords and offset your tables and text.    I think there's something you can do with relative wrapper divs though.

Comment: I'm not wanting to add it within the map div.  I am wanting to add content underneath the entire tab section altogether. The problem is the new content does not bump up to the bottom of the tab container, the new content winds up underneath the map rather than at the bottom of the tab section. http://jsfiddle.net/67wu9/18/

Comment: Just checking to make sure but did you check my fiddle?

Comment: That's what I was looking for!!  But now it is covering up my footer. lol.  What can I do to remedy that?  Just have the wrapper include the footer too on this particular page?

Comment: You could, but right now I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it all.  Is absolute absolutely necessary?  As you've seen it tends to screw a lot of things up.

Comment: I doubt it is necessary.  If you take it off of the wrapper `div`, remove `float` and `position: relative;` from the `#4552130` div, things work just fine in your fiddle.  Seems to be a case of throwing every style at a problem instead of only the ones needed.

Comment: I suggest you don't accept this answer.  Small amounts of text are ok with the absolute wrapper but anything substantial will break the page.  If Miller's comment works go with that.

Comment: Jeremy, That worked on my website.  Thank you.  Do you want to create an answer for me to accept?